# Why is this counting function finite? (It is used Probability)

Tags: calculus, probability, combinatorics, functions

[image]

Why is this counting function finite? I don't understand this interpretation of the author. Can you explain more about this? Please.

Answer (score 1):

I think: A progresseion can only have one limit.  I.e., infinity in this case.  That is, only a countable number of elements of $\alpha_n$ can be below $t$ and if you count them you get a number which is smaller than infinity.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**.  Recall the definition: $\alpha_n\to\infty$ means

> for every $t$ there exists $N$ such that for every $n>N$ we have $\alpha_n>t$.

So, the values of $n$ for which $\alpha_n\le t$ are only (some of) $1,2,\ldots,N$.  That is, the set
$$\{n\mid \alpha_n\le t\}$$
has at most $N$ elements and therefore is finite.

I'll leave you to fill in any necessary details to show that if $\alpha_n\to\infty$ then every $N_{\{\alpha_n\}}(t)$ is finite.

Conversely, if all these sets are finite then every one of them has a maximum element.  For any $t$, if you call the maximum element $N$, then you have the above definition pretty much straight away and so $\alpha_n\to\infty$.  Again there are some details for you to fill in.